# Broken pedal on an old french bike

Tags: repair, pedals

I broke the pedal of an old french bike (Peugeut Mixte 70's). The threading doesn't fit the one in modern pedals.

Now I am wondering if I should insist in finding an old french pedal or if I should rethread the pedal support in order to be able to use modern pedals.

Though, I am a bit scared about rethreading. Can it really be done safely? Is the space between threads the same? Has anyone here done this?

Comment: If you have the tools to remove the crank arm, it might be the best solution would be to take it to a machine shop where they would know if it could be reliably rethreaded.  Or rely on our old friend [Sheldon Brown](http://sheldonbrown.com/velos.html).

Comment: (Remember that you need a left-hand tap on the left side.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It hasn't been difficult to get french pedals direcly from the French ebay! :-)

Answer (score 7):

To quote [Sheldon](http://sheldonbrown.com/velos.html#pedal):

> Older French bicycles used a different, smaller diameter where the
>   pedal screws into the crank, 14 mm x 1.25 mm.
>
> The vast majority of French bicycles imported into the U.S. used
>   standard 9/16" x 20 tpi crank threading, but if you find an older
>   bicycle that was bought in France, you may run into this problem. The
>   French-thread cranks can be tapped out to 9/16". This is much easier
>   (and more worth the trouble) with aluminum cranks. Start the taps from
>   the inside of the cranks,so any possible thread damage occurs where it
>   doesn't matter. French pedals will often be marked "G" (Gauche=left)
>   and "D" (Droite=right).

Answer (score 5):

Yes, a pedal can be reliably enlarged and retreaded, assuming there is enough metal surrounding the original threaded hole. Most good shops have taps for 1/2" and 9/16" pedals, which are the 2 modern standards.

The older French standard is 14mm with a 1.25mm pitch.

It is possible to tap out 14mm to 9/16" without issue, if you have the tools and a steady hand.

Make sure you use the correct tap for the correct crank arm, as the left arm is reverse threaded.

I hope that is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

..Here in France we have the same problem...impossible to find french pedals with old standard M14/125...IMPOSSIBLE.
But it is possible to find in Spain, new french pedals M14/125 around 10 euros...certainly from China. http://www.vicma.es/epages/Vicma.sf/en_GB/?ObjectPath=/Shops/Vicma/Products/W10
Try Ebay too.
Write " PEDALES 14X125" or  "PEDAL M14/125" on Google